# How to set the default value for float in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I wish to set a default value for a property on a model:

```
priority = sa.Column(sa.Float, server_default='0.5')
```

But it does not get set in table:

```
priority double precision,
```

Comment: Try `priority = sa.Column(sa.Float, server_default=0.5)`.

Comment: `A FetchedValue instance, str, Unicode or text() construct representing the DDL DEFAULT value for the column.`

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default), `server_default` needs a `FetchedValue` instance, str, Unicode or `text()` construct representing the DDL DEFAULT value for the column. Therefore, you could try `priority = sa.Column(sa.Float, server_default=u'(0.5)')`. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart `sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type double precision: "(0.5)"`

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart it works without the brackets, thanks: `priority double precision DEFAULT 0.5::double precision,`

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, this is what i used to solve it.

```
server_default=u'0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into this question using SQL Alchemy and Alembic.

text() solved the issue for me

```
from sqlalchemy import text

class MyTable(Base):
    default_float_column = Column(Float, nullable=False, server_default=text("3.0"))
```